# Post de Summernote WYSIWYG em PHP não leva HTML

Tags: php, html, debug, summernote

Tenho um campo `textarea` usando Summernote WYSIWYG, estou fazendo um post para uma página php. mas o post leva apenas texto, as tags HTML ele não carrega para o post.

Abaixo tenho o html que contem a tag `textarea`

```
<form method="post" action="debug.php">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="recipient-name" class="form-control-label">Recipient:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
  </div>
  <div class="">
    <div>
      <textarea class="summernote" id="m_summernote_1" name="conteudo_textarea">

      </textarea>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
</div> </form>
```

Aqui tenho o jQuery

```
var SummernoteDemo={init:function(){$(".summernote").summernote({height:150})}};jQuery(document).ready(function(){SummernoteDemo.init()});
```

Aqui tenho a página PHP (debug.php) que criei para debugar o post

```
<?php echo '<pre>'; print_r ($_POST);  die;
```

Aqui tenho o retorno desse debug em array

```
Array
(
    [conteudo_textarea] =>                  
Prezado (a) Senhor (a)                                                                                                                                                             

Verificando nossos arquivos, não identificamos o pagamento da (s) cota (s) abaixo relacionada (s) .

Tendo em vista a possibilidade de ter ocorrido um problema envolvendo a baixa bancária de seu recibo, pedimos a especial gentileza de nos encaminhar cópia do seu comprovante de PAGAMENTO, o que poderá ser feito via e-mail (cobranca@jetroadm.com.br), a fim de promovermos a devida regularização, tanto junto ao banco, quanto em nossos registros.

Caso a sua unidade esteja em processo de entrega junto à MRV, solicitamos que entre em contato com a Construtora através do canal de atendimento ao cliente para obter informações a respeito do direcionamento da cobrança da cota condominial para a sua unidade.

Informamos ainda, que no caso de não pagamento da (s) mesma (s), serve a presente como aviso de débito, comunicando que, caso não ocorra nenhum contato por parte de V. Sa. afim de obter opções de negociações, a cobrança será encaminhada para o setor correspondente.



)
```

como posso proceder para que o meu post receba o texto do summernote com a mesma formatação ? Preciso dessa informação dessa forma, pois o post com o conteúdo será enviado por email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faz sentido porque o teu form está a pegar o valor do textarea e não o código contido lá.

Para obteres o código basta acessares o método `code()`, e assim fazes uma requisição `ajax` para o ficheiro **debug.php**:

```
var textareaValue = $("#m_summernote_1").code();
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "debug.php",
    data: { summernote_input: textareaValue }
})
```

**debug.php:**

```
var_dump($_POST['summernote_input']);
```

Comment: 13dev , Funcionou aqui. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.